# Interrupt TV program in Android TV

Tags: android, television

We all know Android TV is a new thing. I don't have an Android TV at home, and nothing I found on the net about this.

Consider I have an Android TV and I developed an android app for it. The user is watching TV channels and at this time a new message is arrived at my android application, what I want here at this situation is to notify the user somehow, so that the application interrupts the TV and display a notification that there is a new message arrived or even display the message. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you not just hook into the notification manager like any android device?

Comment: Is there a visible notification manager while the user watches TV?

Comment: From the Android TV documentation, there is a recommendation service that acts like notifications, but they are more than just simple messages

Comment: Yes i saw that but I don't think this what I want, it seems that the recommendation list is something that is not visible until the user presses a button on the remote. Isn't that?

Comment: I mean the user will not see the new message untill he presses the recommendation button. But i don't have an android tv, i can't confirm this. Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Android TV's notification system works the same as Android in general. You can set up Google Cloud Messaging so a service runs when pinged. When this service runs, you can do something like display a toast or open an activity.

The notification manager on Android TV will post recommendations to the home screen, and there is not a general notification drawer. However, all the background components work the same so you can develop a custom UI instead of generating a notification.